# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException error

Tags: java

I believe I wrote all my code correctly but I'm getting this error. Can someone help me understand?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
at gangPackage.newClass.main(newClass.java:15)
```

Here is my code:

```
package gangPackage;

import java.util.*;

public class newClass {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        int age;
        double gpa;
    
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        name = Scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter students age: ");
        age = Scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your GPA: ");
        gpa = Scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf(name + " is " + age + " years old. And has a GPA of " + gpa);
    }
}
```

Comment: What were your inputs?

Comment: Your code is correct. I think the input during GPA (line 15, as what the error says) are not in double format, maybe you entered a non number input

Comment: @Mark My Inputs were: Hotam for the name 19 for the age, and 3.9 for the GPA, when i put a single digit in the GPA it runs fine. and even adds a 0 at the end for example If i put 3, it will print 3.0

Comment: I think you need to add some more code to check input. try to use Scanner.hasNext...() method.

Comment: I executed your code with your input. It works well, no error was thrown

Comment: @Mark Maybe it has to do with eclipse? Im curious in what you run the code in

Comment: @HotamYusupov it has nothing to do with the IDE, I am also running it with eclipse. Try your input again and you will realize that it is working correctly

Comment: @Mark These are my exact inputs Enter your name: 
hotam
Enter students age: 
19
Enter your GPA: 
3.9  <<< this is exactly where i get the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks OK.

An `InputMismatchException` occurs in a `Scanner` when a given input doesn't match the expected input format. Your exception occurs on line 15, where a scanner expects a decimal number such as `3.14` (which, depending on your system's locale, the decimal can be represented by a dot `.` or a comma `,`!)

If you're certain that the input you're providing is absolutely a decimal number, but you're not sure what locale you're using, you can force a particular locale by using the `useLocale` method.

```
Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(sc.hasNext()){
String record = sc.nextLine();
Scanner stringScan = new Scanner(record);}
```

try this before name = Scan.nextLine();

Comment: First of all, adding your code snippet to the code in the question, according to your instructions, will cause the code to not compile since the name of the `Scanner` variable is `Scan` (and not `sc`). I copied the code from the question and added your snippet (after changing `sc` to `Scan`) and I still managed to reproduce the problem, i.e. I got `InputMismatchException`. So please explain in more detail how to use your code snippet to solve the problem. In any case, an incorrect answer is still considered to be a valid answer on SO.

Answer (score -3):

when you enter a double or a float, enter with a comma (,) not a period (.) when the console asks you to enter a value.